# Iterating over a matrix and a list of times to plug into nls function in R

Tags: r

I have spent a fair amount of time searching for an answer to my novice question and am still confused. I am trying to plot initial magnetization of an FID versus time. My initial magnetizations are in a matrix and my time values corresponding to each column of the matrix is a list. How do I run the nls for a exponential decay over each column of data with the corresponding value in the list of times? I am trying to have the nls function input the first time value from the list and run use the initial magnetization values columnwise and return the rates in a matrix of the same dimensions as m0_matrix.

```
> m0_matrix
          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]               
 [1,]  19439311560 15064186946 11602185622  9009147617    
 [2,]   9437620734  7135488585  5348160563  4156154903  
 [3,]  11931439242  9584153017  7765094983  6470870180  
 [4,]   9367920785  7612552829  5927424214  4331819248  
 [5,]  12077347835  8892705185  6866664357  5530601653  
 [6,]  20191716524 15729555553 11920147205  8964406945  
 [7,]  20177137879 15744074858 12364404080  9971845743  
 [8,]  15990100401 12464163359  9724743390  8294038306  
 [9,]  19409862926 16085027074 13110425604 10330007806  
[10,]  15367044986 11994945813  9565243969  7535061239 

r2_from_decay_matrix = matrix(data = NA, nrow = nrow(m0_matrix), ncol =       
ncol(m0_matrix))

t <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)

for (i in seq(1,nrow(m0_matrix))) {

    m0 <- m0_matrix[,i]
    t <- t[i]
    r <- 1

    mCPMG_function <- function(m0, t)
        results <- paste(a = m0, b = t) 

    mCPMG_formula <- mCPMG ~ m0*exp(-r*t)

    fit_start <- c(m0= 19439311560, r=1)
    fit_data <- list(m0=m0, t=t)

    r2 <- nls(mCPMG_formula, fit_data, fit_start)

    r2_from_decay_matrix <- r2$m$getPars()["r"][i]
}
```

Thank you for helping!